# FQDN in SQL connection string

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, azure-sql-database

We have an azure website and an azure VM
 our SQL instance is on the VM.

I am trying to craft a connection string that will allow the azure site to see the SQL box

using the FQDN doesn't seem to work

any help would be greatly appreciated

Thanks

Comment: Try using `localhost`? Or `127.0.0.1`?

Comment: The website is an azure website. the SQLserver is on ANOTHER Azure VM. localhost wont work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to (not so wide) open a port for the SQL Server on VM. You can do this by setting an [Endpoint](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-machines-set-up-endpoints/). The good thing is that an Endpoint has a Public port (this is what Internet sees) and a Private Port (this is where the connection goes on the VM itself). Thus easily masking the default port 1433. My personal advise is that you NEVER open public port 1433 for your Server. Even in that scenario, I would advice you to use [ACL on the Endpoint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn376543.aspx) to only allow connections from Azure web sites in the [DataCenter your web site is deployed](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn175718.aspx). As stated in the last referred article, you shall not assume that traffic originating from Azure DataCentres is trustworthy, but at least you limit the attack surface for your SQL Server.

You may also evaluate using [Hybrid Connections](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/integration-hybrid-connection-overview/) with a VM, but I never tried it.

Another side of the story is that you may want to consider using [SQL Azure](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/sql-database/) (sorry, Azure SQL Database) instead of maintaining own SQL Server. Then your connection will be securely established without a lot of hassle.

Comment: Thank you. I did suggest using an Azure DB but the architect wanted a VM.  Thanks again